# "No database selected" error even after a db is selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have selected the database but for some weird reason it still says that it is not selected.

Connection lines:

```
$location = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

//Database Selection
$link = mysql_connect($location, $user, $pass); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Database Selection
mysql_select_db('database') or die(mysql_error());
```

The Query:

```
while ($row_fpages = mysql_fetch_array($result_fanpage))
{
    if ( $row_fpages['client'] == NULL ) {

    //GRAPHS
    $sql = "SELECT date, likes FROM statistics_pages WHERE idnum='".$_COOKIE['id']."' AND page_name = ".$row_fpages['page_name']." LIMIT 7";
    $result_apps = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

And the error is a plain `No database selected`.

I have never seen this error before and i tried to change a lot of things but its just not working.

Comment: This can also happen if your mysql_query command commands *before* your call mysql_connect or mysql_selectdb commands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to pass the variable $link as the link parameter.

```
     mysql_select_db('database', $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT:** Try passing the database in the FROM parameter like

```
     SELECT * FROM `database`.`table`
```

Comment: That would not be necessary. If there's no link specified the last link opened will be assumed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: Oh yeah ? Didn't know... It's true. Thanks for the info !

Comment: I think Marcus is right but i decided to check this out anyway and it doesn't help.

Comment: `SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'statistics_pages'` it seriously looks like it doesn't recognize the connection lines...

Comment: At least we know it is not the database but the entire link. You said you did this before, try to copy your older code, past it where you need it and edit the credentials.

Comment: i have the entire connection in a `config.php` file, i have just copied it from there but nothing helps.. all the other functions with `config.php` included are working but this one isn't. I'm confused now.

Comment: It is very weird. But for looping you must have a query before in your code, is she working ?

Comment: I have found the problem bro, i have just included a file that already has the `config.php` included so it was making the error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason why this error pops up is because the **username and password which you are using to access the database may not have appropriate read/write persmissions**.
Especially on a shared hosting server, you will need to assign the appropriate username to the corresponding database. 
I recently had this problem, I had created a new database and forgot to assign persmissions for my existing username.

Answer (score 2):

May be mysql's user permissions on the database you are selecting?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have added the user to the db and gave him appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code isn't inserted into classes and stuff, if it's just presented as is, then perhaps 'database' isn't valid, double check your values and try making it an external variable.

Comment: `database` is valid and i don't even use classes in my code.. :\

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
Use ` backticks for MYSQL reserved words...
your table name  is reserved word for MYSQL...
Change your table name.